# Managing bower file with Angular files

Tags: angularjs, bower

Ok, I think that this is an easy question. I am new to Bower, and I am trying to keep my bower.json file in sync with the multiple libraries that Angular now provides. I am using angular-resource, angular-cookies, angular-sanitize, angular-animate, and then the main angular library. In my bower.json file I have all of these listed as dependencies, but I am having to update 1.2.4 to 1.2.5 for each of these items.

I am sure there is an easier way, and as I understand it I can do "~1.2" for each item and get all of the 1.2.x updates when doing a bower install. But if I want to get specific versions, do I have to update all of the strings to 1.2.5 or can I have a variable somewhere in the bower.json that I can reference, and just update that one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have variables in your bower.json file, so its not supported out of the box.

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter-bower/OvMPG6KS3OM/eo6L2VadxI8J

As a workaround if you have `sed` you can run something like:

```
# update 1.2.5 -> 1.2.7 in test.json
sed -i '' 's/1.2.5/1.2.7/' test.json
```

Comment: Hrm, too bad. what was " It's not that hard to update two lines once in a while." is now updating 8 lines on a weekly basis (with Angular's weekly releases and all of the different modules). Its still not a difficult task, however I felt like it was something that was worth looking into.

Comment: Yes the bower folks should fix this. Murphy's law will kick in at some point. Not to mention inaccurate manual merges.